# Align buttons to the bottom of a sidebar in grid css

Tags: html, css

Question: How do I make a sidebar and align the buttons at the bottom and center them into the sidebar using grid css?

[image: sketch of desired layout]

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  width: 40px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  
}

.bot {
  align-items: bottom;
}

.circle-btn {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <nav>
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="bot">
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>  
</div>
```

Comment: Anything you can do in a Codepen you can do in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/2518285).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is `grid-template-rows`. Set the second row to `auto`, which means it will be sized to fit its contents, then set the first row to `1fr` which means it will consume all the remaining space.

```
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.d1 {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px auto;
}

nav {
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255,0.4);
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  justify-items: center;
}

nav>* {
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.top {
  background: #500;
}

.bot {
  background: #055;
}

.circle-btn {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

main {
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <nav>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bot">
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
      <div class="circle-btn"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main>
    press the full page link to see this properly
  </main>
</div>
```